# How to use the same event for a SVG-set on begin and end?

Tags: svg

I am trying to define a "popup" that toggles when certain element is clicked.
Something like this:

```
<text id="t" x="498" y="207" visibility="hidden">hello
  <set attributeName="visibility" from="visible" to="hidden" 
  begin="t.click" end="t.click"/>
</text>
```

Any ideas how can i accomplish this using set?

The solution using Javascript is straightforward but i need it to be a "set", if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two elements to do a toggle as far as I can see. You can't make an animation depend on CSS property state but you can make event handling do so.

```
<text id="t2" x="498" y="207" visibility="hidden" pointer-events="all">hello
</text>
<text id="t" x="498" y="207" visibility="visible">hello
  <set attributeName="visibility" from="visible" to="hidden" 
  begin="t.click"/>
  <set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" 
  begin="t2.click"/>
</text>
```

Comment: Sadly it does not resolves my problem, but it works for the example i gave

Answer (score 0):

I have made a working example using SET command. [Simple popup in SVG using SET (SMIL)](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/VLMEwg/)

```
<g opacity="1">
<text x="30" y="80">Click the green circle to see the text</text>
<set attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="btnOn.click" end="btnOff.click" />
</g>
```